# Rails 2.3.x: Call other controller from within a controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, action

Is it somehow possible to call another controller's action from within a controller? `redirect_to` is not what I need, because I've stored the request information (path, params, referer, xhr, ...) of another request and want to execute it now. Basically an `exec` for controller actions would be what I need. Simply instantiating the controller, setting the needed instance variables and calling the action is not enough, because this does not invoke the right filters and error handlers.

Comment: Can you show us your code? This isn't how MVC should work, and Ill bet if you showed us the relevant code we could tell you how to solve your issue a different way.

Answer (score 2):

No. You can't do this. This is why with the MVC pattern you hear people recommend "skinny controllers".

Move the logic down into the models as much as possible. Then it's easy to share across controllers. Or you can try moving the similar actions into a shared controller so that they can share behaviour.

Comment: For what I need this: Anonymous user tries to do action X. This action needs the user to be logged in. Therefore this action has a special filter associated that returns a login form if not logged in and stores the request data in the session so it does not need to be retransmitted. Then the user logs in and the remembered action gets executed. How should *that* be possible using models?

Comment: Ok, that's a pretty standard pattern. Maybe put the before_filter in your ApplicationController (or some other controller higher up in the inheritance chain) and apply it as needed? Or you could put this in a model using `Thread.current` and some such trickery. It depends how much code there is to it. Is this a 15 line filter? Or 150 lines? If you're interested in the trickery behind models that interact with session, take a look at the AuthLogic source code.